# How to append json output in html table with editable tr using for loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I am  working with codeigniter framework, so as per my requirement I am getting user data from database and encoding by `json_encode`, as in php we use `foreach` loop to echo data in table, but because of json this data should appended in table using for loop in jquery script and here  I got stuck, so how to do this  i.e user data appended in table one by one.with editable `<tr>`

Controller  code

```
public function get_users() {

   $result = $this->db->get('users')->result();
   header('Content-Type: application/json');
   echo json_encode($result);

}
```

Jquery ajax to get output in json

```
 $.ajax({
        url: "<?= base_url('controller/get_users') ?>",
        type: 'POST',
        data: {},
        success: function (response) {
             console.log(response);
            var arr_output=JSON.stringify(response);

          // For loop code to append each  user data in table with  editable tr

        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            alert(xhr.status);
        }
    });
```

Html table

```
<table class="append_data">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>mobile not</th>
    <th>city</th>
    <th>edit</th>z
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: `// For loop code to append each  user data in table with  editable tr`  You should make some _attempt_ to do this yourself

Comment: @PatrickQ actually I tried this after parsing json data but getting 'undefined' so question posted without  for loop code

Comment: If you are getting errors, you should post the code that generates the errors, along with the exact error text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean to have something along the lines of this?

Of course I've not included your source code in my answer, but it's simply enough to essentially copy and paste. In my example I'm making use of a funtional style approach, i.e. making use of [currying](https://hackernoon.com/currying-in-js-d9ddc64f162e), [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) and not to mention the [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function.

I guess all you'd really need to do in this scenario is pass the table and the data from the AJAX `success` function into the render function that I've provided, I'm just assuming that the data returned from the server is an array of objects.

```js
// The HTML table.
const tbl = document.querySelector('.append_data');

// Some example data.
const dummyData = [
  {name: 'demo', mobile: '01748329', city: 'NY', edit: 'Something'},
  {name: 'test', mobile: '12345789', city: 'WA', edit: 'Something Else'}
];

// A function to produce a HTML table row as a string.
const template = d => `<tr>
    <td>${d.name}</td>
    <td>${d.mobile}</td>
    <td>${d.city}</td>
    <td>${d.edit}</td>
  </tr>`;

// A function that takes a table, returns a function to accept an arrya of objects.
// It will then add the relevant template(s) to the provided table. 
const render = tbl => d => tbl.innerHTML += d.map(i => template(i)).join('');

// Fire the render function. 
render(tbl)(dummyData);
```

```html
<table class="append_data">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>mobile</th>
    <th>city</th>
    <th>edit</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

## Edit

I've also made use of [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) in my first example, here's a more beginner friendly implementation.

```js
// The HTML table.
var tbl = document.querySelector('.append_data');

// Some example data.
var dummyData = [
  { name: 'demo', mobile: '01748329', city: 'NY', edit: 'Something' }, 
  { name: 'test', mobile: '12345789', city: 'WA', edit: 'Something Else' }
];

// A function to produce a HTML table row as a string.
var template = function template(d) {
  return '<tr>' 
  + '<td>' 
  + d.name 
  + '</td>' 
  + '<td>' 
  + d.mobile 
  + '</td>' 
  + '<td>' 
  + d.city 
  + '</td>' 
  + '<td>' 
  + d.edit 
  + '</td>' 
  + '</tr>';
};

// A function that takes a table, returns a function to accept an arrya of objects.
// It will then add the relevant template(s) to the provided table. 
var render = function render(tbl) {
  return function (d) {
    return tbl.innerHTML += d.map(function (i) {
      return template(i);
    }).join('');
  };
};

// Fire the render function. 
render(tbl)(dummyData);
```

```html
<table class="append_data">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>mobile</th>
    <th>city</th>
    <th>edit</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

## Edit 2

If I'm not mistaken, you need to remove `JSON.stringify` in order for this to work correctly with the code I've provided. Within the code I've provided, you can see, my code expects an `object` to be provided, and if you're using `JSON.stringify`, then that *essentially* converts an object to a string... In which case, this code will not work... Maybe you should do a bit more reading into how to use methods like [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) & [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

Comment: ca you please explain what is d here '  const template = d =>  ' I am not familiar with this.

Comment: Sure thing, that's just the same as `function (d) { ...`, the idea being that `d` is just short for `data`.

Comment: @Anonymous I've also included a more 'beginner friendly' implementation with my most recent edit, I hope you're more familiar with that syntax! :)

Comment: sure i will check now thank you so much for this code

Comment: @Anonymous You're very welcome! :) It's all a part of the service, haha! :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186802/discussion-between-jo3-w3b-d3v-and-anonymous).

Answer (score 0):

```
var output = myJSON;  //from succss:function(myJSON)
  var html = '';
  $.each(output,function(key,value){
      html +='<tr>';
      html +='<td>'+ value.name + '</td>';
      html +='<td>'+ value.mobile + '</td>';
      html +='<td>'+ value.id + '</td>';
      html +='</tr>';
  });
$('.append_data tbody').append(html);
```